# Mysql - deleting duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table with a barcode column with a unique index. The data has been loaded with additional chars (-xx) at the end of each barcode to prevent duplicates, but there will be lots of duplicates once I strip off the suffix. Here is a sample of the data:

```
itemnumber  barcode

17912       2-14
18082       2-1
21870       2-10
29219       2-8
```

Then I created two temporary tables, marty and manny, both with the itemnumber and the stripped down barcodes. So,both tables would contain

```
itemnumber  barcode

17912       2
18082       2
21870       2
29219       2
```

etc

And the I tried to delete all but the first entry with barcode '2' in the marty table(and every other barcode). I hoped then to update the original table with the correct first entry and the users could fix up the duplicates themselves in time in the application.

So, this was my query to delete all but the first entry in the marty table for each barcode

```
DELETE FROM marty
  WHERE itemnumber NOT IN
    (SELECT MIN(itemnumber) FROM manny GROUP BY barcode)
```

There are 130,000 rows in marty and manny. The query took over 24 hours and then didn't finish properly. The connection to the server crashed and the query did not do all the updates.

Is there a better way to approach this that would not us the subquery, which i think is causing the delay? And the group by is probably slowing things down too with so many records.

Thanks

Comment: Is `itemnumber` unique?  If yes, I think your approach would eventually work, despite being inefficient because it searches the entire "manny" table for each row of "marty".

Answer (score 2):

One more variant: this variant works without any temporary tables for deleting duplicates:

```
 Delete m1
 From Marty m1
 join Marty m2 
    on m1.barcode = m2.barcode 
    and m1.itemnumber > m2.itemnumber
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is notoriously slow when using `IN` with very large sets. A scripted alternative:

Use a script to construct a long `itemnumber = X OR itemnumber = y OR itemnumber = z` clause (chunks size ~1000) and `INSERT` the matched rows (i.e. the ones that would not have been `DELETE`d in your previous query) into a new table, `TRUNCATE` the existing and load the contents of the new table back into the old with `INSERT INTO marty SELECT * FROM marty_tmp`.

You may want to lock the table or run in a transaction for the final `TRUNCATE`, `INSERT`.

**edit:**

- Query `SELECT MIN(itemnumber) FROM manny GROUP BY barcode` from a script, store results in desiredItemNumbers array
- Take batches of 1000 desiredItemNumbers and construct this query: `INSERT INTO manny_tmp SELECT * FROM manny WHERE itemnumber = desiredItemNumbers[0] OR  itemnumber = desiredItemNumbers[1] ...`. Rerun this query until you've exhausted the desiredItemNumbers array (n.b. the last query will probably have less than 1000 desiredItemNumbers).
- You now have a table with the results that you would have been left with had you `DELETE`d the rest, so swap the contents of the `marty` and `marty_tmp` tables.
- `TRUNCATE marty`
- `INSERT INTO marty SELECT * FROM marty_tmp`

Comment: Hi Andy, I don;t quite follow "construct a long........" I am still going to have to identify the first itemnumber of a list of duplicate barcodes. That is where i have the problem, the only way I know to achieve that is to use the select in and the group by, which is too slow. MartinMac

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two-stage approach that avoids use of `NOT IN`.  It also does not use the temporary table "manny".  First, join "marty" to itself to pick out rows for which itemnumber != min(itemnumber).  Use `UPDATE` to set `barcode` for these rows to `NULL`.  A second pass with `DELETE` then removes all rows that were flagged in the first phase.

For this example, I split the `barcode` column of "marty" into two columns; it could be done with the table in its original format with some modification (need to split the column values on the fly).

```
select * from marty;
+------------+---------+---------+
| itemnumber | barcode | subcode |
+------------+---------+---------+
|      17912 |       2 |      14 |
|      18082 |       2 |       1 |
|      21870 |       2 |      10 |
|      29219 |       2 |       8 |
|      30133 |       3 |       5 |
|      30134 |       3 |       7 |
|      30139 |       3 |       9 |
|      30142 |       3 |      12 |
+------------+---------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

UPDATE
  (marty m1
   JOIN
     (SELECT barcode,
             MIN(itemnumber) AS itemnumber
      FROM marty
      GROUP BY barcode) m2
   USING(barcode))
SET m1.barcode = NULL WHERE m1.itemnumber != m2.itemnumber;

mysql> select * from marty;
+------------+---------+---------+
| itemnumber | barcode | subcode |
+------------+---------+---------+
|      17912 |       2 |      14 |
|      18082 |    NULL |       1 |
|      21870 |    NULL |      10 |
|      29219 |    NULL |       8 |
|      30133 |       3 |       5 |
|      30134 |    NULL |       7 |
|      30139 |    NULL |       9 |
|      30142 |    NULL |      12 |
+------------+---------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

DELETE FROM marty WHERE barcode IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating temp tables anyway, how about building your table with an "INSERT INTO " or "CREATE TABLE .. AS ..." based on:

```
SELECT MIN(itemnumber) AS itemnumber, barcode
  FROM marty
  GROUP BY barcode
```

Comment: Glenn, that's great. Nice and simple, really fast and it worked fine. I just had to use a substr(barcode,1,length(barcode)) to strip away the suffix that had been used. Thanks a million.